# Asp.Net Core 3.1 Web Api Attempt To Update a Record Deletes it

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to implement an Update call in my Asp.Net Core 3.1 Web API.  I have a very simple table

```
Id    Name    Active  CreatedById CreateDate UpdatedById UpdateDate CompanyId RefId
310   HSE       1       54566     12/2/2021                              8
```

I am using Postman to attempt to rename the department and add a Ref Id:

[image]

Here is my Web API code:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("~/api/entity/UpdateDepartment")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateDepartment([FromBody] TblCompanyDepartmentsXlu department)
    {
        try
        {
            Type dept = typeof(TblCompanyDepartmentsXlu);
            int DepartmentId = await companyService.FindDepartment(department.Id, department.RefId);
            TblCompanyDepartmentsXlu Department = await context.Departments.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == DepartmentId);
            foreach(PropertyInfo prop in dept.GetProperties())
            {
                var vally = department.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                if(vally !=null)
                {
                    dept.GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(Department, department.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(department));
                }
            }
            int EmployeeCompanyId = employeeService.GetEmployeeCompanyId(HttpContext);
            Department.UpdateById = EmployeeCompanyId;
            Department.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok("Department updated successfully!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Problem(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I have tried the above code with and without `context.Departments.Update(Department)` before `await context.SaveChangesAsync()`, but either way, it deletes the department instead of updating it.  I have also tried with and without using Reflection.

Comment: `"I have also tried with and without using Reflection."` then what happed when you get rid of using reflection?

Comment: The same thing.  It deletes it.

Comment: I even tried the "entry" method: Context.Entry(await Context.MyDbSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == item.Id)).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);  And it deletes it too!

Comment: I got your point, could try this way explained on our [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Let us know if that resolve your problem, feel free to share if any further issue you would encountered.